# Polymer custom behavior generates lint error

Tags: polymer, behavior, lint

I have created a custom behavior that extends the AppLocalizeBehavior:

```
var JM = window.JM || {};
JM.AppLocalizeBehavior = {
    properties: {
        myVar: String,
        value: 'a string'
    }
}
JM.AppLocalizeBehavior = [Polymer.AppLocalizeBehavior, JM.AppLocalizeBehavior];
```

My component imports this behavior:
    ...
    behaviors: [JM.AppLocalizeBehavior]
    ...

And the dom-module has the binding:
[[localize('hello','name','John')]]

When I run `polymer lint` I get the error:
Computed Binding method 'localize' is not defined on element '...'

When I change the name to `JM.LocalizeBehavior` I get additionally:
`Behavior JM.LocalizeBehavior not found when mixing properties into ...`

Using the default Polymer.AppLocalizeBehavior does not generate any lint error.

What do I need to add to the code to prevent the linting errors?

Comment: Try this advice: https://github.com/PolymerLabs/polylint/issues/83#issuecomment-172387621

Comment: I already annotated it. The funny thing is that if I change the name into LocalizeBehavior (without App) I get an additional Lint warning:
`Behavior JM.LocalizeBehavior not found when mixing properties into ...`

Comment: Update: 
The errors only occur when the behavior and component are not in the same folder.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. Maybe you should ask on [Polylint's github](https://github.com/PolymerLabs/polylint/issues)